# htaccess 301 redirects and errordocument

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a .htaccess that is supposed to do the following:

1. Redirect URLs from old Website to new pages
2. Redirect to custom 404 page if file is non-existent

This is my Code:

```
    Redirect 301 /oldpage.php /newpage

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,R=404]
    ErrorDocument 404 /404
```

My problem is: The redirect does not go to /newpage instead queries to /oldpage.php are redirected to /404

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
//Custom 404 errors
ErrorDocument 404 /path/to/custom/404.php    

//301 Redirect from a specific Old File to new
Redirect 301 /oldpage.php /newpage.php

//301 Redirect from a different URL path
Redirect 301 /posts http://mywebsite.com/blog

//301 Redirect from an old directory to a new directory
RedirectMatch 301 /old-directory/(.*) /new-directory/$1
```

Comment: So basically you are saying, that I should dispose of the rewriteCondition before the ErrorDocument 404 part in order to make the redirects work? That is not working at all, unfortunately. In this case I get the /404 in both cases but the redirects do not work.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. the 404 should be on top!

Comment: Could you beef up your answer a bit? Some explanation and reference links? That would help people to understand *why* this works. You might want to read [How Do I Write A Good Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Is not working for me either. In this case all I get is the /404 page, redirects do not work